# Recommended way to add a new page to html5 boilerplate project for repeated content

Tags: html, html5boilerplate

How should I add a new page to a HTML5 Boilerplate project?

The problem is that if I copy a base page, if I change the menu or the layout, then I have to change all the pages containing that layout.

I don't want to use server side includes because I want to host the website on IIS or Apache.

Or I should use HTML5 Boilerplate for SPA only?

Comment: Wow, that was a fast downvote!!! And no clue why ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use templates to avoid duplicating content (like a menu for instance). Then you need to “compile” your website, that is to insert the content into the templates.

There are tools like [Hammer](http://hammerformac.com) that help doing this, or you can do it by hand using [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io) or any other template system.

Comment: At this moment I'm using jsrender and jquery ajax to load the content, but I want something more like the master pages in asp.net. I will see your suggestions, thanks a lot!